# JavaFX, DataFX and server-side code

Tags: javafx, glassfish

I'm looking at enterprise JavaFX, and how to integrate JavaFX with server-side code.  In the last few weeks I've done a certain amount of research in DataFX and Open Dolphin, and downloaded some videos, as well as looking at a couple of other frameworks.  For example I've looked at the video on DataFX at:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EN4fo6x0DcQ

However, although this video and others I've looked at explain how to set up a client application that connects with a server, I've found very little information on how to put together some server-side code that the client can connect to.  Sure, one could use JAX-RS, but why re-invent the wheel?  In the first instance I would like to put together some really simple server-side code that some test client-side code can connect to using DataFX or one of the other frameworks.  The aim eventually is to get a client using JavaFX to communicate with a server.

My second question is that of the various frameworks available, is DataFX the best to use for a simple application?

I have experience with a Glassfish server hosting a JSF application, and it may be useful to have such a server hosting a JSF application communicating with a browser as well as communicating with a client JavaFX, as that way I can test out that the communication with the JavaFX application.

The latter is a bit of an aside, and my main questions are where can I get information on server-side programming for this, and the best frameworks to use?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to manage yourself the client-server communication you can pick any JavaFX Application Framework listed there:

https://github.com/mhrimaz/AwesomeJavaFX

Any of them allows to separate UI code from communication code.

As I'm author of JRebirth, I can advice you to create some RemoteService (extends Service and providing JAX-RS facilities or whatever) to perform this job.

If you search an all-in-one library managing client AND server side, DataFX + OpenDolphin is probably the most advanced one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of DataFX & Dolphin Platform (https://github.com/canoo/dolphin-platform). Both are valid frameworks that fill fit to your needs. Maybe a combination of both - Dolphin Platform as remoting layer between client and server and DataFX to define the routing and mvc based views on the client.

Some days ago I copied all the DataFX sources to GitHub (https://github.com/guigarage/DataFX) and currently trying to create a new version based on the modules that are maintained by me. Maybe I will extract the MVC related stuff and create a new framework based in it, we will see. What I currently can say is that I plan to work on it the next month next to the Dolphin Platform since I think a combination of both will be a good fit.

I would use this combination today to create applications but yeah, I'm the main developer of both frameworks so the choice is quite easy for me ;)

As you mentioned JSF I think that Dolphin Platform is a perfect match for you since one idea of the framework is to have a modern successor for JSF that can be used to create desktop & web based applications but provide managed controllers on the server. We provide a cool maven based jumpstart (Maven archetype) that will give you a quick introduction and a runnable client / server application with a desktop and web client in 2 minutes: https://canoo.github.io/dolphin-platform/#_dolphin_platform_jumpstart